# How to trigger intent on existing conversation in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I am trying to trigger a intent on a conversation that already exist.  I am using cloud function and I am currently passing the session ID to it, however, this seem to be not enough to reference an existing conversation, how do I tell it to send the response to an existing conversation?

```
const triggerCallback = (sessionId, message) => {

  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({projectId: projectId, keyFilename: keypath});
  
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId,sessionId);
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    sessionId: sessionId,
    queryInput: {
      event: {
        name: eventName,  
        languageCode: LANGUAGE_CODE
      },
    },
  };
  response = sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  
  return response.then(response => {
    console.log('intent detected');
    const result = response[0].queryResult;
    console.log(`Query: ${result.queryText}`);
    console.log(`Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);

    if(result.fulfillmentText) {
      console.log(result.fulfillmentText);
      return result.fulfillmentText;
    }
    else {
      console.log('no intent found');
    }
  });
};

exports.Callback = (req, res) => {
  let sessionId = req.query.sessionId || req.body.sessionId || '';
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  triggerCallback(sessionId, message)
  .then((response)=>{
    res.status(200).send(response);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Trigger bot error! ', JSON.stringify(error));
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  });
};
```

Here is my code, and it does trigger the event, and get the response, however it doesn't send it to the session ID that's specified though.

[image]

I am calling it in postman like this:

```
https://us-central1-gcp-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/myCloudFunction?sessionId=dfMessenger-55251706
```

Do I need to pass anything else to tell it to respond to an existing conversation?

EDIT: I should add that I get the correct response in postman, I just don't see it in my web channel session:

Comment: I tried your code and encountered an error at `sessionClient.sessionPath()` and says "it is not a function". I changed it to [sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/v2.SessionsClient.html#projectAgentSessionPath). Other than this error, code works fine for me. All succeeding requests are being grouped into the specified session id. I'm using `"@google-cloud/dialogflow": "^4.3.1"` as the dependency.

Comment: Hi Ricco, I just want to ask if you actually got a message?  I don't get any error neither but I don't see anything.  Also, which channel are you using?

Comment: It just returned a response 200 in Postman. I checked the conversations in Dialogflow Console -> History. It shows that when using a single `session ID` for detectIntent, the requests are grouped into one conversation.

Comment: Yeah it "works" for me in postman too but I don't see the response in chat UI.

Comment: Can you show the intents used and how to trigger them in the existing conversation you are pertaining to?

Comment: 1.) Can you upload your agent along with index.js, and package.json that you are using on a public repo like GitHub? Just make sure that there are no project ids, API credentials, etc. included. 2.) Are you using any type of integration or API? Like how are you interacting with the dialogflow agent. 3.) Just to confirm, what are the exact steps to reproduce your issue? 4.) Can you provide a sample interaction with your bot as well? Ex. User input-> hello, Bot replies-> Hi, how can I help?, User input-> please book a flight to 6pm, Bot replies-> which seat would you like? ...

Comment: Hey Ricco, Google engineer has told me to try using a different channel than the built in messenger I was testing with, so I am going to try it with Genesis.  If it work, I will post the result here!